# Social login with hybridauth not working in php

Tags: php, curl

I am developing a site with social login. I use the library hybridAuth. but it is not working. I am not providing the script here because i think the error is not because of the script. The error message is  'got an error! Hybridauth Library needs the CURL PHP extension.' I am working in localhost. I would like to know how to install CURL in my windows 7 operating system.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Comment: thanks i got it right